# How to get date with year change in java

Tags: java, localdate

My method has following fields - id, year and month.

```
Collection<User> userCollection = getUserForMonth(int id, int year, int month);
```

User give me range of date. Between fromTimestamp and toTimestamp. I have to use method getUserForMonth so but I have no idea how to change these parameters (year and month) dynamiclly.

From timestamp I make start and end dat like that

```
LocalDate startDate = new Timestamp(csvRaportTransport.getFromTimestamp()).toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();
LocalDate endDate = new Timestamp(csvRaportTransport.getToTimestamp()).toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();
```

I can set up year and month like getStartDate but I do not know how to switch it.

I though about for but how change months and years? Have no idea. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: Start [there- LocalDate javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). I guess `plusYears`, `plusMonths` is what are you looking for.

Comment: getUserForMonth(int id, int year, int month) is not applicable for date ranges unless if you are trying to get all months between the date range and call the method for each and every month

Comment: @Shadi yes, I try to get all months and years between. I can not use plusMonth/plusYear because I might miss some dates.

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Are you trying to get a start and stop date as a range to query a database for rows carrying a date that falls in that range?

Comment: @Tom Your comment makes no sense. Please revise your Question for clarity. Voting to close as `unclear what you're asking`.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome  `java.sql.Timestamp` class is now legacy, replaced by [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) as of JDBC 4.2 and later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all the users for all months between startDate and StartYear you can do like:

```
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 01, 1);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 03, 1);
    while(startDate.isBefore(endDate))
    {
        getUserForMonth(123,startDate.getYear(), startDate.getMonthValue());
        startDate = startDate.plusMonths(1);//.plusYears if you want years
    }
```

If you want to get the user for specific month in relations to startDate and endDate you can use:

```
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 01, 1);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 03, 1);

    getUserForMonth(123,startDate.getYear(), startDate.getMonthValue());
    getUserForMonth(123,endDate.getYear(), endDate.getMonthValue());
```

I hope it helps. 
As mentioned by user **xxxvodnikxxx**, you can read more about this in LocalDate javadoc provided in his comment

Comment: I strongly recommend using `isBefore` instead of `equals`.

Comment: I used isBefore to your while loop. The problem is that if I use dates 2017-12-29 and 2018-01-05 I can not get 2018 year.

Comment: Changed to isBefore based on Max's comment.
Why you are not able to get the correct year? i am getting below response  when i run:
while(startDate.isBefore(endDate))
  {
   getUserForMonth(123,startDate.getYear(), startDate.getMonthValue());
   startDate = startDate.plusDays(1);
   System.out.println(startDate);
  }

console:
2017-12-30
2017-12-31
2018-01-01
2018-01-02
2018-01-03
2018-01-04
2018-01-05

Comment: I made some mistake. Now it works. Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

to get all months in between date range use

```
    public List<LocalDate> getMonthsBetween(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        long numOfMonthsBetween = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startDate, endDate);
        if(numOfMonthsBetween == 0){
        // means that start and end dates are in the same month
            return Collections.singletonList(startDate);
        }
        return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i+1)
            .limit(numOfMonthsBetween)
            .mapToObj(i -> startDate.plusMonths(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

then you can iterate over the dates

```
getMonthsBetween(LocalDate.now(),LocalDate.now().plusMonths(11)).stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

this will yelled

```
2018-03-26
2018-04-26
2018-05-26
2018-06-26
2018-07-26
2018-08-26
2018-09-26
2018-10-26
2018-11-26
2018-12-26
2019-01-26
```

simply in the forEach call your getUserForMonth(int id, int year, int month) 
to get the result for each and every month and add the sub-result to the final Collection that you plan to return